# Failed to allocate OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I am having some crashes due to a memory issue. The logs I get are more or less like these ones:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 557942800 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 374MB until OOM, target footprint 169310272, growth limit 536870912
       at com.appacoustic.rt.domain.calculator.processing.ToDoubleSamplesKt.toDoubleSamples(ToDoubleSamplesKt.java:25)
       at com.appacoustic.rt.domain.calculator.ReverbTimeCalculator.invoke(ReverbTimeCalculator.java:25)
       at com.appacoustic.rt.framework.audio.recorder.Recorder.stop(Recorder.java:25)
       at com.appacoustic.rt.framework.audio.recorder.Recorder$stop$1.invokeSuspend(Recorder.java:12)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(BaseContinuationImpl.java:2)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.java:2)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoop.processUnconfinedEvent(EventLoop.java:2)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuationKt.java:120)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(CancellableKt.java:9)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.java:9)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.java:9)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.java:4)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(BuildersKt.java:4)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(BuildersKt.java:4)
       at com.appacoustic.rt.presentation.measure.MeasureViewModel$handleStartClicked$1$1.onFinish(MeasureViewModel.java:23)
       at com.appacoustic.rt.domain.ButtonStateHandler$start$1.onFinish(ButtonStateHandler.java:4)
       at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:127)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 216662032 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 43MB until OOM, max allowed footprint 516134168, growth limit 536870912
       at com.appacoustic.rt.domain.calculator.processing.SchroederIntegralKt.schroederIntegral(SchroederIntegralKt.java:1)
       at com.appacoustic.rt.domain.calculator.ReverbTimeCalculator.calculatePosition(ReverbTimeCalculator.java:1)
       at com.appacoustic.rt.domain.calculator.ReverbTimeCalculator.invoke(ReverbTimeCalculator.java:7)
       at com.appacoustic.rt.framework.audio.recorder.Recorder.calculateReverbTime(Recorder.java:7)
       at com.appacoustic.rt.framework.audio.recorder.Recorder.stop(Recorder.java:15)
       at com.appacoustic.rt.framework.audio.recorder.Recorder$stop$1.invokeSuspend(Recorder.java:12)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(BaseContinuationImpl.java:2)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.java:2)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoop.processUnconfinedEvent(EventLoop.java:2)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuationKt.java:120)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(CancellableKt.java:10)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.java:8)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.java:8)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.java:4)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(BuildersKt.java:4)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(BuildersKt.java:4)
       at com.appacoustic.rt.presentation.measure.MeasureViewModel$handleStartClicked$1$1.onFinish(MeasureViewModel.java:23)
       at com.appacoustic.rt.domain.ButtonStateHandler$start$1.onFinish(ButtonStateHandler.java:4)
       at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:127)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

What I am doing here are audio processing operations.

For example:

**[toDoublesSamples](https://github.com/soygabimoreno/RT/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/appacoustic/rt/domain/calculator/processing/ToDoubleSamples.kt)**

```
fun ByteArray.toDoubleSamples(): DoubleArray = mapPairsToDoubles { a, b ->
    (a.toInt() and 0xFF or (b.toInt() shl 8)).toDouble()
}

inline fun ByteArray.mapPairsToDoubles(block: (Byte, Byte) -> Double) =
    DoubleArray(size / 2) { i ->
        block(
            this[2 * i],
            this[2 * i + 1]
        )
    }
```

Or this one:

**[schroederIntegral](https://github.com/soygabimoreno/RT/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/appacoustic/rt/domain/calculator/processing/SchroederIntegral.kt)**

```
fun DoubleArray.schroederIntegral(): DoubleArray {
    val out = DoubleArray(size)
    for (index in indices) {
        out[index] = this[index] * this[index]
    }

    var aux = out[0]
    for (index in 1 until size) {
        aux += out[index]
        out[index] = aux
    }

    return out
}
```

I am not pretty sure what' wrong here. I guess it is related to enough memory spent, but I am using at most 1 seconds of 44100 Hz signals.

Surely it is a silly thing, maybe related to Doubles waste too much space or something similar. But I don't know how to fix it.

BTW, the crashes are a little bit random. It does not happen always.

The repo is here if you want to dig deep into it:
https://github.com/soygabimoreno/RT

Any idea to fix it? :-)

Comment: Post the full stacktrace of the OOM.

Comment: In your second case, you are trying to allocated a single contiguous block of memory of 557942800 bytes = 532MB. There are Android devices where *the entire system RAM* is less than that. "Any idea to fix it?" -- the stack trace should show you precisely where your memory allocation is coming from.

Comment: Debug and see how big is the ByteArray you're passing `toDoubleSamples()`.

Comment: I have added some logs to see it in https://github.com/soygabimoreno/RT/commit/587b2f5189e65172c1b0f3eb1a24cfcfcf5d46a9, @m0skit0. The sizes are normal: the byte array has around 0.15 MB and the converted double array, 0. 60 MB.

Comment: The stacktrace definitely disagrees with your debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly error. I was calling twice the `AudioRecord.startRecording` due to a state problem in another place.

BTW, I was getting a `-38` error. Actually, I started to record and it stopped at the moment a memory error happened.